# Sorting a huge file in desired order

Tags: python, linux, sorting, bigdata

I have data in the following form:

```
<j> <l> <n> "jd".
<K> <J> <N> <D>.
<A> <B> <D> <F>.
<E> <F> <G> "abc".    
<A> <B> <C> <D>.
<G> <k> "jd" "l".
```

I need to sort the data such that only the odd lines get sorted and the corresponding even lines get sorted according to the odd lines. i.e. the sorting of the file happens using only the odd lines i.e. only the following lines get sorted:

```
<j> <l> <n> "jd".
<A> <B> <D> <F>.
<A> <B> <C> <D>.
```

to

```
<A> <B> <C> <D>.
<A> <B> <D> <F>.
<j> <l> <n> "jd".
```

And the even lines get copies as it is. For example a sorted order of the above will be:

```
<A> <B> <C> <D>.
<G> <k> "jd" "l".
<A> <B> <D> <F>.
<E> <F> <G> "abc".    
<j> <l> <n> "jd".
<K> <J> <N> <D>.
```

Now the even line `"<G> <k> "jd" "l"."` always appears after the odd line `"<A> <B> <C> <D>."` and the even line `"<E> <F> <G> "abc". "` always appears after the odd line `"<A> <B> <D> <F>."` and the even line `"<K> <J> <N> <D>."` appears after the odd line `<j> <l> <n> "jd".`

I tried to use linux sort command with parallel option for the same as my file size is 200 GB -- but by doing so the order of the odd lines gets disturbed. Is there some way using linux sort command or using some python program I may achieve the desired behaviour of 200 GB file

Comment: You need something like `map-reduce`

Comment: find a solution for the subset of the problem: 4 lines only. Then you should be able to do this with python, by splitting into different files.

Comment: You probably will need a sorting algorithm that is efficient using hard-drive as storage, for example mergesort or similar.

Comment: @taesu My problem is I am not able to find such a solution

Comment: problem is I dont get the sorting algo for your subset of the problem, or it requires too much brainpower!

Comment: Write a program that splits your file into two files: one with 'odd' lines and one with 'even' lines. Sort the files containing even lines. Write a program that merges the two files back into one file.

Comment: Is _all_ of the data like that? I.e, each line consists of 4 space-separated fields and terminated by a `.`, with each field being a letter enclosed by  `<` and `>` (aka, angle brackets), or a short sequence of letters enclosed by double quotes `"`?

Comment: @PM2Ring yes that is the case

Comment: @dsh: That won't work. Each even line has to travel with its associated odd line.

Comment: @dsh the merging will not preserve the order after getting sorted

Comment: @RoseSharma: Excellent! In that case, it's easy. I'll explain the general technique in an answer.

Comment: `sort` sorts lines, not pairs of lines or anything like that. If you want to use `sort` you need to transform each pair of lines into one line, sort, then transform back.

Comment: @PM2Ring ah, I missed that part of the uniqueness of this requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using linux, I assume that you have vim installed (a minimal version comes by default on my ubuntu machine.
If not, install it first.

I believe vim can handle large files without choking (unlike notepad)

1. **Using vim, merge every line with the one beneath it**

*input.dat*

```
<j> <l> <n> "jd". 
<K> <J> <N> <D>.
<A> <B> <D> <F>.
<E> <F> <G> "abc".
<A> <B> <C> <D>.
<G> <k> "jd" "l".
```

> `ex input.dat -c 'g/^/j' -c 'sav! joined.dat' -c q`

*joined.dat:*

```
<j> <l> <n> "jd".  <K> <J> <N> <D>.
<A> <B> <D> <F>a  <E> <F> <G> "abc".
<A> <B> <C> <D>.  <G> <k> "jd" "l".
```

g is the global command which matches every line which has a line start (^) (that's every line) and executes the join command.
After that, you'll have every even line appended to its previous uneven line separated by two spaces.

Then it saves (overwriting!) as joined.dat and quits

2. **Sort the joined.dat file like normally do with the sort command**

*Sorted.dat*

```
<A> <B> <C> <D>.  <G> <k> "jd" "l".
<A> <B> <D> <F>a  <E> <F> <G> "abc".
<j> <l> <n> "jd".  <K> <J> <N> <D>.
```

3. **"Unjoin" what you joined on the first step**

> `sed 's/.  /.\n/' sorted.dat > finishedproduct.dat`

This assumes your initial file has a dot at the end of each line.

Note: If you use the same file as input and output with sed, I believe you could get as a result a blank file.

*finishedproduct.dat:*

```
<A> <B> <C> <D>.
<G> <k> "jd" "l".
<A> <B> <D> <F>.
<E> <F> <G> "abc".
<j> <l> <n> "jd".
<K> <J> <N> <D>.
```

In this scenario, sed basically replaces a dot and two spaces for a dot and a newline, effectively replacing the two spaces introduced by vim to join the lines.

I know it isn't a very elegant solution (much less pythonic) but it circumvents the "having to write a custom program" and the memory issues it involves. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I agree that it's a good idea to use the Linux `sort` program because it's very efficient and can handle sorting files that are much larger than RAM. The trick is to transform your data before & after sorting so that `sort` can do what you want.

You need to read the data in a loop that reads two lines at a time, joins the two lines together into one line and writes the new lines out to a new file.

Next, sort the new file, telling `sort` to only sort on the first 4 keys in a line.

Now read the sorted data, line by line, splitting each line in two, and writing the splitted data to the final destination file.

The line splitting and joining programs can easily be written in awk or Python. I suggest trying to write them yourself, but if you have problems getting them to work properly I'll be happy to help (and I'm sure others on SO will be, too. :)